# How to stop for loop in cypress? After 'else' condition I need to stop it

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, cypress

I need to stop the for loop in else condition, after the else condition is done. But it continues, What should I do?

### I updated the codes as below but still it continues to click.

[Here the cypress log SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze37p.png)

```
cy.get('app-video-preview').as('videos')
for(let i=0; i<4 ; i++)//there are 5 videos to be check if active or completed
    cy.get('app-video-preview').each(($videos)=>{
          if($videos.eq(i).find(('mat-icon')).is(':visible')){//if a video has check icon
             cy.log('completed')//will write this text
          }else{
           cy.get('@videos').eq(i).click()//else, will click video
           return false; 
          }       
         })
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read the docs about [`.each()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Syntax). It will loop array or object type structure.

```js
cy.get('app-video-preview').as('videos')
cy.get('@videos').each( $video =>{
  if($video.find(('mat-icon')).length > 0){
    cy.log('completed')
  }else{
    cy.wrap($video).click()
    return
  }      
})
```

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Return-early -> That's the specific part of the documentation about returning early.

Comment: I tried but didnt work.

Comment: cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 5 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element.   -> when I run the code above. @jjhelguero

Comment: That was a mistake it should use the `$video`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah, this worked with `"return false"` instead of `"return"`. Thank you so much.